# Leadbolt Interstitials don't show

Tags: android, leadbolt

I'm trying to put some interstitial ads with LeadBolt in my app game, but I don't succeed in doing it.
When a round finishes, I want it to show the interstitial (don't wait too much if there's an error), wait for it to be closed by the user, then continue showing the result. Here's my source, depured by useless code:

```
private void endGame () {
                    // I always arrive here
        loadNewAd(this, new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                showResult();
            } });
}

private void loadNewAd(final Activity act, final Runnable continuation) {
    if (cAd == null)
        cAd = new AdController(act, C.LB_SECTION_ID_INTERSTITIAL, new AdListener() { 
              public void onAdLoaded() { } 
              public void onAdClicked() { continuation.run(); } 
              public void onAdClosed() { continuation.run(); }
              public void onAdCompleted() { continuation.run(); }
              public void onAdFailed() { continuation.run(); }
              public void onAdProgress() { } 
              public void onAdAlreadyCompleted() { continuation.run(); }
              public void onAdHidden() {} // function is deprecated 
              public void onAdPaused() { continuation.run(); }
              public void onAdResumed() { } 
            });
        cAd.loadAd();
}
```

I could not understand if this code works just a few times, or in some specific condition that I didn't understand, anyway just a few times shows the ad, while in the rest it never reaches the continuation.run().

I also don't understand when to call destroyAd(): should I call it every time a single ad is dismissed, or at the end of the lifecycle of the application?

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you.